# CADENCE LAYOUT VIEW

Tags: cadence

Can I send informations from an Cadence schematic view of an electronic circuit ( example like [CADENCE LAYOUT VIEW](http://cadence.okstate.edu/schematics.html) to an other application running on Windows????

Description of the use case:

My program hold an electronic design, this information I send to Cadence as an net list.  Here the user of this application can browse / view the net list and see what has happend.  Sometimes he wants to get more information from my program regarding a special part of the net list.

I need to send decice type, instance information and net informations from cadence to  this second application

He may select in Cadence Layout editor a certain element ( transistor or whatever) or a signal ...  instead of eg. properties display  ... I need  call a function which calls my program on UNIX side and passes a few parms to my application

OK , I could do screen OCR  and send data via TCP/IP from UNIX to Windows. Therefore my plan has thre steps

1) via OCR grap Cadence Information from layout view and get this data as text

2) send informations via ICP/IP  from UNIX to Windows app

3) Windows second app is executing with this Informations

But is there any better way to grap informations from Cadence and bring them to another program running on Windows?

I need Cadence in this contet only for an display of my information

Comment: Have you contacted cadence about this?

Comment: Which Cadence product and version are you using? OrCAD/Allegro/...? What data are you trying to extract? Is this layout (as your title says) or schematic (as the rest of the question states)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: OK...what is the second application, and why are you trying to send this information?  Are you trying to generate a netlist for simulation?

Comment: I haven't touched Cadence in 2 years or so, but can't you just generate a netlist and use it in the other program?

Comment: Four question marks in a row cancels out your question. You should have used five, or even eighty-three.

Comment: the question is not releated to any specific design --- I is about modifiacation / extension of a design tool : CADENCE

Comment: Cadence Virtuoso supports a scripting language called SKILL with some interprocess communication capabilities.  Try searching for tutorials in the (extensive) built-in help. You will find more experts in the [Cadence Forums](http://www.cadence.com/community/forums/), perhaps under [Custom IC SKILL](http://www.cadence.com/community/forums/48.aspx).  I suggest you ask a specific question and not call Virtuoso "Cadence" (that's like calling Powerpoint "Microsoft").

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Cadence, but in most EDA systems, the data is transferred from the schematic capture tool to the layout tool by first creating an intermediate *netlist* file. Many schematic tools also enable exporting to several other netlist formats (aside from the tool vendor's proprietary format) to enable communication with other programs.

The typical way to get data out of a schematic editor and into another program, then, is to generate a netlist file, and then make the other tool able to parse the netlist file to extract the information it needs. If you don't have control of the other program's capabilities, you might need to write a script (e.g. Perly/TCL/Python/...) to translate the netlist file to some format your other program understands.

Comment: I added now more infos, hope It makes clear what I want to do